# Showing one div only out of three and hiding the other two when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I have 3 hidden DIVs on a page. When I click a heading to show one div, the other 2 DIVs should be hidden. I wrote the following code to accomplish this. However it doesn't work well on all browsers such as iPad and iPhone. How can I accomplish the same result with a better code?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script type="text/javascript" Src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head runat="server">
<style>
.div1, .div2, .div3 { display:none; }
</style>

<script>
$(window).load(function () {

    $(".bt1").click(function () {
        $(".div1").css("display", "block");
        $('[class^="div"]:not(.div1').css("display", "none");
    });

    $(".bt2").click(function () {
        $(".div2").css("display", "block");
        $('[class^="div"]:not(.div2').css("display", "none");
    });

    $(".bt3").click(function () {
        $(".div3").css("display", "block");
        $('[class^="div"]:not(.div3').css("display", "none");
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="divID1" class="bt1">bt1</div>
<div id="divID2" class="bt2">bt2</div>
<div id="divID3" class="bt3">bt3</div>
<br />

<div id="id1" class="div1">Content1</div>
<div id="id2" class="div2">Content2</div>
<div id="id3" class="div3">Content3</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a single handler like

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var $divs = $('.div');
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    var $target = $('#' + $(this).data('target')).show();
    $divs.not($target).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div data-target="id1" class="btn">bt1</div>
  <div data-target="id2" class="btn">bt2</div>
  <div data-target="id3" class="btn">bt3</div>
  <br />
  <div id="id1" class="div">Content1</div>
  <div id="id2" class="div">Content2</div>
  <div id="id3" class="div">Content3</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Great code..... It works perfectly well on all browsers. I wish there was one button to accept all answers!

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(".btn").hide();
$(".btnP").click(function() {
  $(".btn").hide();
  $("#" + $(this).data("rel")).show();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div data-rel="btn1" class="btnP">bt1</div>
  <div data-rel="btn2" class="btnP">bt2</div>
  <div data-rel="btn3" class="btnP">bt3</div>
  <br />

  <div id="btn1" class="btn">Content1</div>
  <div id="btn2" class="btn">Content2</div>
  <div id="btn3" class="btn">Content3</div>

</form>
```

Comment: This also works perfectly well on all browsers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common class for button say `bt` and class `div` to div elements

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="divID1" class="bt">bt1</div>
<div id="divID2" class="bt">bt2</div>
<div id="divID3" class="bt">bt3</div>
<br />

<div id="id1" class="div">Content1</div>
<div id="id2" class="div">Content2</div>
<div id="id3" class="div">Content3</div>
</form>
```

and use single handler to achieve this:

```
$(".bt").click(function () {
   $(".div").hide().eq($(".bt").index(this)).show();
});
```

**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h6joke1L/)**

Comment: This also works perfectly well on all browsers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeTab(obj)
{
    $('#contents').find('div').not('#'+$(obj).attr('rel')).hide();
    $('#contents').find('#'+$(obj).attr('rel')).show();
}

$('#form1 div').click(function() { changeTab(this); });
```

Try this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8n6rsvbL/

Comment: This also works perfectly well on all browsers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about using classes or ids: it's up to you ;)

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="btn" data-related-div="div1">bt1</div>
    <div class="btn" data-related-div="div2">bt2</div>
    <div class="btn" data-related-div="div3">bt3</div>
    <br>
    <div class="div1 div">Content1</div>
    <div class="div2 div">Content2</div>
    <div class="div3 div">Content3</div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.div {
    display: none;
}
```

JS using jQuery:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $('.div').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).data('related-div')).show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svf4kb01/)

Comment: This also works perfectly well on all browsers. Thank you